# How to wait till Saga finishes before calling mapDispatchToProps

Tags: react-redux, redux-saga

I created my own normalizer, and it does it's work in a saga, which `put` a load action for each model. For example it could dispatch load for posts and then dispatch load for comments.

My problem is that the moment I dispatch to load for posts, connect runs mapStateToProps and rerenders my components.

I want it to wait till I've run all my load actions (ie. both posts AND comments), before connect runs mapStateToProps and rerenders my component.

Comment: Control the rerender yourself in componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps, nextState) - in there you can tell it not to rerender (by returning false) until your props are filled as you want them.

Comment: Solid solution! Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I used was to call one action called "LOAD_NORMALIZED_DATA" that all of my data reducers listened to. I sent the whole chunk of normalized data to it, and let the reducers pick it apart as they needed.

One action, and therefor one re-render.

Chris Cousins also gave a great per-component solution, which is to use componentWillReceiveProps (or shouldComponentUpdate) and returning false, until the component has the data it needs. [although with normalization this would require a lot of additional state, to keep track of data being stale or not]